# API call with invalid database connection pointer: Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have been working on a project that has two databases to keep track of. I have been getting the following error when I attempts to open the database to insert into a table:

```
API call with invalid database connection pointer
Optional(0x00000001025a9ce2)
```

This is the code for the insert(The above error is printed out with the sqlite3 error message):

```
func insertRating(rating: Double,usrname: String,picture: String) {
    //Open up Users database
    let userDB = UserDatabase().createDB()
    
    print(rating,usrname,picture)
    
    
    let insertStatementString = "insert into Rating (Picture,Rating,UserID_fk) values('" + picture + "','" + String(rating)  + "',(select UserID from Users where Username = '" + usrname + "'))"
    
    var insertStatement: OpaquePointer?
    
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(userDB, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK{
        
        if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Inserted Row")
        } else{
            print(sqlite3_errmsg(insertStatement))
            print("Could not insert row")
        }
        
    } else {
        print("Insert statement not prepared")
    }
        sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
    
        sqlite3_close(userDB)
}
```

I have made sure that throughout the code I have opened and closed the database correctly. No other database is open during the content view, another function just returns an array of image URL that get printed to the string.

I use the following library StarRating, which call a function that passes in various parameters that I want inserted into the table.

```
List(pictureURL, id: \.self) { pic in
            //For each photo in pictureURL
                //Associate with a rating clikced on by the user
            
            LazyVStack{
                if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: pic.photo), scale: 10.0)
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
                StarRating(initialRating: 0,onRatingChanged: {
                    insertRating(rating: $0, usrname: model.usrName, picture: pic.photo)
                    
                })
            }
        }
```

I don't think the star library is the problem. Is there a procedure I am unaware of in regards to the sqlite3 interface that is build into swift?

Edit:
Here is the code for createDB:

```
func createDB() -> OpaquePointer?{
        var db : OpaquePointer?
        
        guard sqlite3_open(path, &db) == SQLITE_OK else {
            print("error opening database users DB")
            sqlite3_close(db)
            db = nil
            return nil
        }
        
        return db
    }
```

Comment: You are calling insertRating in a loop so for each item you open and close the database, I have no idea if this causes the problem but it looks a bit inefficient. Also can you post the code to createDB?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am not sure how else to associate a rating with each picture, anyways the only time that insertRating is called is when I click on a star.

Comment: I see createDB returns an optional value but you never check for nil in insertRating